# how to get from mod_rewrited url query string

Tags: mod-rewrite, get, query-string

I have a liitle mod_rewrite problem.

1. I have index.php (in root directory) which contains simple href link:

   ```
   <a href="novice/this-is-something">Novice</a>
   ```

When I click on Novice, redirects me on novice.php file (which is mod_rewrited, that doesn't look like **novice.php?query=this-is-something** in URL, but looks like **novice/this-is-something** (this-is-something is my query)) The problem is, when I'm trying to GET "this-is-something" query in novice.php file.

I'm getting this query in novice.php file like that:

```
    if (isset($_GET['query'])){
$query=$_GET['query'];

echo $query;
    }else{
echo 'Null parameters.';    
    }
```

**But it outputs just 0**

But when I'm **passing numbers** in href link, like that:

```
    <a href="novice/2131">Novice</a>
```

The output in novice.php file is correct: 2131

I have code in my .htaccess like that:

```
    RewriteRule ^novice/([^/\.]+)/?$ novice.php?query=$1 [L]
```

So what am I doing wrong in mod_rewrite, that i can get numbers through $_GET method, but I can not get string or charachters through $_GET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found solution by myself.**

I've just changed "query" word at the end of RewriteRule ^novice/([^/.]+)/?$ novice.php?**query**=$1 [L]

to

"blabla" word -> RewriteRule ^novice/([^/.]+)/?$ novice.php?**blabla**=$1 [L]

And then works everything... Very strange...

```
    if (isset($_GET['blabla'])){
    $blabla=$_GET['blabla'];

   echo $blabla;
}else{
 echo 'Null parameters.';    
}
```

It echo's now the parameter **this-is-something**.. But still don't know what was the problem.. I've just changed the name of variable "**query**" which was containing parameter "**this-is-something**"..

Btw if someone is interested: my .htaccess looks like this:

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # Unless directory, remove trailing slash
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://localhost/local_ageo.si/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://localhost/local_ageo.si/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
    RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]

    RewriteRule ^novice/([^/\.]+)/?$ novice.php?blabla=$1 [L]
```